# C ¿Por qué no funciona el switch? Siempre ejecuta el case 1

Tags: c

Estoy haciendo un menú de opciones y me he encontrado con un problema: introduzca el valor que introduzca, ejecuta solo el case 1, e incluso me admite valores que no debería ya que está el while!=0. No veo bien dónde está el error porque en códigos similares es similar, por lo que he pensado que a lo mejor es un problema de la variable opcion. Paso el trozo de código dónde creo que debe estar el error. Muchas gracias, espero que alguien vea dónde está el fallo.
(Sobre el main, sé que delante puede ir el int, pero a mí me han enseñado que no es necesario)

```
int opcion;

main (){

    FILE *fichero;
    
    struct ficha fichas [100];
    struct ficha temporal [100];
    
    char nombreFichas [25];
    char tipoFichas [25];   
    char duracionFichas [25];
    char plataformaFichas [25];
    char anioFichas [25];
    
    int contador = 0;
    int contadorfila = 0;
    int fila;
    



    
    do{
        
        menu(opcion);   
        while (getchar () != '\n');
        
        switch(opcion){
        
            case 1:
        
            fichero = fopen("fichas.txt", "a");
            
            pideDatosChar ("Nombre: ", nombreFichas);
            fprintf(fichero,"%s\n", nombreFichas);
            pideDatosChar ("Tipo: ", tipoFichas);
            fprintf(fichero,"%s\n",tipoFichas);
            pideDatosChar ("Duracion: ", duracionFichas);
            fprintf(fichero,"%d\n",duracionFichas);
            pideDatosChar ("Plataforma: ", plataformaFichas);
            fprintf(fichero,"%s\n",plataformaFichas);
            pideDatosChar ("Anio: ", anioFichas);
            fprintf(fichero,"%d\n",anioFichas);
            printf ("------------------------------\n");
            
            strcpy (fichas[contador].nombre, nombreFichas); 
            strcpy (fichas[contador].tipo, tipoFichas);
            strcpy (fichas[contador].duracion, duracionFichas);
            strcpy (fichas[contador].plataforma, plataformaFichas); 
            strcpy (fichas[contador].anio, anioFichas);
            
            fprintf (fichero,"%s\n",nombreFichas);
            fprintf(fichero,"%s\n",tipoFichas);
            fprintf(fichero,"%s\n",duracionFichas);
            fprintf(fichero,"%s\n",plataformaFichas);
            fprintf(fichero,"%s\n",anioFichas);
            
            contador++;
        
            break;
            
            case 2:
                leerFichero();
            break;
            
            case 3:
                pideDatosChar ("Por favor, introduce el nombre de la pelicula o serie que quieres buscar: ", nombreFichas);
            break;
            
            case 4:
                
            break;
            
            case 5:
            break;
            
            case 6:
            break; 
            
            case 0:
                printf ("Has salido del programa");
            break;
            
            default: 
                printf ("El numero introducido no es valido", opcion);
            break;
            
            }   
        
    }while (opcion != 0);
    
}
```

Aquí añado la función menu para que se vea más claro.

```
int menu(opcion){

    
    printf ("\t Opcion 1: Introducir una nueva serie o pelicula \n");
    printf ("\t Opcion 2: Lee el listado completo  \n");
    printf ("\t Opcion 3: Busca una ficha por el nombre de la pelicula o serie\n");
    printf ("\t Opcion 4: Listado ordenado por año o nombre \n");
    printf ("\t Opcion 5: Generar un documento HTML con nombre especifico \n");
    printf ("\t Opcion 6: Generar documentos HTML \n");
    printf ("\t Opcion 0: Salir \n");
    printf ("\t Elige una opcion: \n");
    scanf ("%d", &opcion);
    }
```

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! opcion tiene siempre el mismo valor, el resultado de menu() (que no se que es).. por eso nunca cambia...

Comment: Gracias, lo leeré. Sin embargo, aunque cambie eso, se sale siempre del programa y sigue sin funcionar.

Comment: Al ver de nuevo este código lo reconocí. ¿Como te fue desde mi ultima ayuda?.

Comment: creo que ya tienes suficiente puntos si quieres te ayudo con el código en este chat: https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/30872/stack-overflow-en-espanol

Answer (score 3):

Tu error es que no usas punteros, aunque ese sea tu propósito:

```
int menu(opcion);
```

Realmente no se como te compila el código por esta parte, en c siempre se debería especificar el tipo de datos que un parámetro debe tener. De Acuerdo a tu código debe ser un puntero a entero o simplemente retornar lo que almacena scanf:

```c
void menu(int* opcion){//Lo puse como void porque no retornará nada esta función. Y al declararlo puntero hay que modificar dos lineas:
```

- `scanf("%d,&opcion);` como lo pusimos como puntero deberíamos omitir el "&" porque ya de por si estaríamos pasando la dirección almacenado dentro de ese puntero,debe quedar asi: `scanf("%d",opcion);`.
- `menu(opcion);` deberias cambiarlo a `menu(&opcion);` para pasarle la dirección de memoria al parámetro.
- Meter la variable global dentro de main, ¿porque? porque tu código no necesita que sea global, pero si quieres dejarlo global entonces no pases ningún parámetro a la función menu y tampoco le declares ningún parámetro: `void menu(){` y `menu();`.

Otra forma seria usar el retorno(tu función al declararla int debería retornar un entero, vamos a aprovechar que tu función retorna un entero para retornar la opcion escogida por el usuario y asi no tienes que usar punteros:

```c
int menu(){//como no necesitamos parámetros podemos omitirlo
    int opcions;//Donde almacenamos scanf
    //... todos tus prinft aquí.
    scanf("%d",&opcions);
    return opcions;
}
int main(){
...
 opcion=menu();
```

Otra forma como sale en los comentarios seria asignarle directamente el valor a la variable global opcion y quitarle el parámetro y el retorno a la función:

```c
void menu(){
    //... todos tus prinft aquí.
    scanf("%d",&opcion);
}
```

Y lo llamamos sin pasarle ningún parametro:

```c
int main(void){
    //tu codigo...
    menu();
   //...
```

Comment: Cabe mencionar que la variable `opcion` en su código original la declara como variable global. También podría asignarla directamente.